# glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) makes the whole screen white, instead of just the background

Tags: c++, opengl

When I draw shapes on a black background with `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`, everything gets drawn perfectly on a black background, like this:

[image]

Now when I increase the RGB closer to white (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0), things get fade out, like this:

[image]

When it's white, everything is completely fade out:

[image]

Changing the alpha to 0.0 doesn't make a difference either. I'm calling these two functions at the beginning of each frame (and their order doesn't make a difference):

```
glClearColor(clear_color.x, clear_color.y, clear_color.z, clear_color.w);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

What I want is obvious: to be able to see my blue arrows on white background.

Comment: Do you have blending enabled when you draw the arrows? Otherwise I wouldn't see how the background color could influence the drawing. It might be good to add the code where you draw the arrows so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BDL Thank you for reminding me about blending stuff. Apparently, I had `glBlendEquation(GL_MAX);` set, so that was causing a problem. Getting rid of it fixed the issue. Please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as the working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior described in the question can only happen when blending is enabled while drawing the arrows. Disable blending before drawing and everything should work as expected:

```
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```